# Is there a way to do groupby in pandas such that same feature is used in both row and columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Input table:

```
person    cat1    cat2
   P1        A    X
   P1        B    X
   P2        A    X
   P2        B    Y
   P3        A    X
   P3        B    Y
```

Required table:

```
             B
        X    Y    Z
     X  1    2    0
A    Y  0    0    0
     Z  0    0    0
```

The aggregation function can be unique persons - `nunique()`

Code till now:
`df.groupby(['cat1','cat2']).person.nunique().unstack()`

But this does not give the right table. Any help on how to do this?

Comment: why does it assumes that the count of A, X is equal to B, Y (perhaps this is why it cannot be done in an obvious way)?

Comment: P2 and P3 are essentially same rows with different person number

Comment: How is his operation called mathematically?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly ugly, but seems to do the job:

```
df1 = df.groupby('person').apply(lambda g: 
    g.pivot_table('cat2', None, 'cat1', aggfunc=lambda x: x)
)
df2 = df1.reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
df3 = df2.pivot_table(None, 'A', 'B', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x))
```

Now sure how efficient it is on "Big Data" (TM).

Essentially, `df1` contains as many columns as the values for `cat1`, filled with the value in `cat2`:

```
cat1         A  B
person           
p1     cat2  X  X
p2     cat2  X  Y
p3     cat2  X  Y
```

`df2` is the same with clutter removed:

```
cat1 person  A  B
0        p1  X  X
1        p2  X  Y
2        p3  X  Y
```

and `df3` contains the result:

```
  person   
B      X  Y
A          
X      1  2
```

Comment: not working. ```Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (1, 1)```

Comment: @Mysterious In your question, is `person` an index or a column in the dataframe?

Comment: it is a column in the dataframe

Comment: @Mysterious it works with your example though, `df = pd.DataFrame({'person': ['p1', 'p1', 'p2', 'p2', 'p3', 'p3'], 'cat1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'cat2': ['X', 'X', 'X','Y', 'X', 'Y']})`